# Trigger Async Function on Other Pages by Calling it in Non-Async Constructor in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xamarin, .net-core

In my App, there is an Async Function `ProcessOffer()`. When I called it in Constructor as `ProcessOffer`, it works but synchronously. I want to call this Function in constructor asynchronously.

The `ProcessOffer()` is a function implemented in `CredentialViewModel`, but I want that, It should be triggered asynchronously everywhere on the App (`IndexViewModel` e.t.c).

If I'm on the `IndexPage`, and Web Application sends a request to Mobile Application, `ProcessOffer()`, should be triggered.. actually what `ProcessOffer` does is, that it asks the user to enter a PIN, if it's correct, it sends back a response to the Web Application.

I've tried answers from other Posts, but they returned the Error `Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: 'An exception was thrown while activating App.Name`, when I sends a request to Mobile App from Web Application.

The Solutions I tried.

1- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64012442/14139029

2- `Task.Run(() => ProcessOffer()).Wait();`

3- `ProcessOffer().GetAwatier().GetResult();`

**CredentialViewModel.cs**

```
namespace Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.Credentials
{
    public class CredentialViewModel : ABaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly CredentialRecord _credential;
        private readonly ICredentialService _credentialService;
        private readonly IAgentProvider _agentContextProvider;
        private readonly IConnectionService _connectionService;
        private readonly IMessageService _messageService;
        private readonly IPoolConfigurator _poolConfigurator;

        [Obsolete]
        public CredentialViewModel(
            IUserDialogs userDialogs,
            INavigationService navigationService,
            ICredentialService credentialService,
            IAgentProvider agentContextProvider,
            IConnectionService connectionService,
            IMessageService messageService,
            IPoolConfigurator poolConfigurator,
            CredentialRecord credential
        ) : base(
            nameof(CredentialViewModel),
            userDialogs,
            navigationService
        )
        {
            _credential = credential;
            _credentialService = credentialService;
            _agentContextProvider = agentContextProvider;
            _connectionService = connectionService;
            _messageService = messageService;
            _poolConfigurator = poolConfigurator;

            _credentialState = _credential.State.ToString();

            if (_credentialState == "Offered")
            {
                ProcessOffer();
            }
        }

        [Obsolete]
        public async Task ProcessOffer()
        {

            foreach (var item in _credential.CredentialAttributesValues)
            {
                await SecureStorage.SetAsync(item.Name.ToString(), item.Value.ToString());
            }

            var RegisteredPIN = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("RegisteredPIN");
            string PIN = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayPromptAsync("Enter PIN", null, "Ok", "Cancel", null, 6, Keyboard.Numeric);
            if (PIN == RegisteredPIN)
            {
                try
                {
                    //await _poolConfigurator.ConfigurePoolsAsync();
                    var agentContext = await _agentContextProvider.GetContextAsync();
                    var credentialRecord = await _credentialService.GetAsync(agentContext, _credential.Id);
                    var connectionId = credentialRecord.ConnectionId;
                    var connectionRecord = await _connectionService.GetAsync(agentContext, connectionId);
                    (var request, _) = await _credentialService.CreateRequestAsync(agentContext, _credential.Id);
                    await _messageService.SendAsync(agentContext.Wallet, request, connectionRecord);
                    await DialogService.AlertAsync("Request has been sent to the issuer.", "Success", "Ok");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    await DialogService.AlertAsync(e.Message, "Error", "Ok");
                }
            }
            else if (PIN != RegisteredPIN && PIN != null)
            {
                DialogService.Alert("Provided PIN is not correct");
            }
        }

        #region Bindable Command
        [Obsolete]
        public ICommand ProcessOfferCommand => new Command(async () => await ProcessOffer());

        public ICommand NavigateBackCommand => new Command(async () =>
        {
            await NavigationService.PopModalAsync();
        });
        #endregion

        #region Bindable Properties
        private string _credentialState;
        public string CredentialState
        {
            get => _credentialState;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _credentialState, value);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**IndexViewModel.cs**

```
namespace Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.Index
{
    public class IndexViewModel : ABaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly IConnectionService _connectionService;
        private readonly IMessageService _messageService;
        private readonly IAgentProvider _agentContextProvider;
        private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
        private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;

        public IndexViewModel(
            IUserDialogs userDialogs,
            INavigationService navigationService,
            IConnectionService connectionService,
            IMessageService messageService,
            IAgentProvider agentContextProvider,
            IEventAggregator eventAggregator,
            ILifetimeScope scope
            ) : base(
                "Index",
                userDialogs,
                navigationService
           )
        {
            _connectionService = connectionService;
            _messageService = messageService;
            _agentContextProvider = agentContextProvider;
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            _scope = scope;
        }

        public override async Task InitializeAsync(object navigationData)
        {
            await base.InitializeAsync(navigationData);
        }

        public class Post
        {
            public string Success { get; set; }
            public string firstname { get; set; }
        }

        [Obsolete]
        public async Task ScanVerification(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code
        }

        public async Task SettingsPage(SettingsViewModel settings) => await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync(settings, null, NavigationType.Modal);

        #region Bindable Command
        public ICommand SettingsPageCommand => new Command<SettingsViewModel>(async (settings) =>
        {
                await SettingsPage(settings);
        });

        [Obsolete]
        public ICommand ScanVerificationCommand => new Command(async () => await ScanVerification(default, default));
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**App.xml.cs**

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace Osma.Mobile.App
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public new static App Current => Application.Current as App;
        public static IContainer Container { get; set; }

        // Timer to check new messages in the configured mediator agent every 10sec
        private readonly Timer timer;
        private static IHost Host { get; set; }

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            timer = new Timer
            {
                Enabled = false,
                AutoReset = true,
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds
            };
            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        }

        public App(IHost host) : this() => Host = host;

        public static IHostBuilder BuildHost(Assembly platformSpecific = null) =>
            XamarinHost.CreateDefaultBuilder<App>()
                .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddAriesFramework(builder => builder.RegisterEdgeAgent(
                        options: options =>
                        {
                            options.AgentName = "Mobile Holder";
                            options.EndpointUri = "http://11.222.333.44:5000";

                            options.WalletConfiguration.StorageConfiguration =
                                new WalletConfiguration.WalletStorageConfiguration
                                {
                                    Path = Path.Combine(
                                        path1: FileSystem.AppDataDirectory,
                                        path2: ".indy_client",
                                        path3: "wallets")
                                };
                            options.WalletConfiguration.Id = "MobileWallet";
                            options.WalletCredentials.Key = "SecretWalletKey";
                            options.RevocationRegistryDirectory = Path.Combine(
                                path1: FileSystem.AppDataDirectory,
                                path2: ".indy_client",
                                path3: "tails");

                            // Available network configurations (see PoolConfigurator.cs):
                            options.PoolName = "sovrin-test";
                        },
                        delayProvisioning: true));

                    services.AddSingleton<IPoolConfigurator, PoolConfigurator>();

                    var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
                    containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyModules(typeof(CoreModule).Assembly);
                    if (platformSpecific != null)
                    {
                        containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyModules(platformSpecific);
                    }

                    containerBuilder.Populate(services);
                    Container = containerBuilder.Build();
                });

        protected override async void OnStart()
        {
            await Host.StartAsync();

            // View models and pages mappings
            var _navigationService = Container.Resolve<INavigationService>();
            _navigationService.AddPageViewModelBinding<MainViewModel, MainPage>();
            _navigationService.AddPageViewModelBinding<RegisterViewModel, RegisterPage>();
            _navigationService.AddPageViewModelBinding<IndexViewModel, IndexPage>();
            _navigationService.AddPageViewModelBinding<SettingsViewModel, SettingsPage>();
            _navigationService.AddPageViewModelBinding<CredentialsViewModel, CredentialsPage>();
            _navigationService.AddPageViewModelBinding<CredentialViewModel, CredentialPage>();

            if (Preferences.Get(AppConstant.LocalWalletProvisioned, false))
            {
                await _navigationService.NavigateToAsync<MainViewModel>();
            }
            else
            {
                await _navigationService.NavigateToAsync<ProviderViewModel>();
            }

            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Check for new messages with the mediator agent if successfully provisioned
            if (Preferences.Get(AppConstant.LocalWalletProvisioned, false))
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var context = await Container.Resolve<IAgentProvider>().GetContextAsync();
                        await Container.Resolve<IEdgeClientService>().FetchInboxAsync(context);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        protected override void OnSleep() =>
            // Stop timer when application goes to background
            timer.Enabled = false;

        protected override void OnResume() =>
            // Resume timer when application comes in foreground
            timer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my View Models, if i need to initialize asynchronously I usually pass OnAppearing() to the view model instead of the constructor.  Someone can tell me if this is unwise but it solved my needs.

Code Behind View:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CredentialView : ContentPage
{
    public CredentialView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new CredentialViewModel();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        ((CredentialViewModel)BindingContext).OnAppearing();
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class CredentialViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public CredentialViewModel ()
    {
    }

    public async void OnAppearing()
    {
        await ProcessOffer();
    }

 }
```

Also just FYI, the biggest gotcha i've experienced with asynchronous code on xamarin is to use BeginInvokeOnMainThread.  It's my understanding that touched UI should be executed on main thread! (probably why they call it the UI thread. haha)
Example:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    observableCollection.Clear();
});
```

Comment: ABaseViewModel probably already implements INotifyPropertyChanged. That doesn't matter though, nothing in the shown code actually uses that interface. Understand the code, don't just copy paste.

Answer (score 1):

Look, you have `public override async Task InitializeAsync(object navigationData)` method in the `IndexViewModel` class. I suppose the framework invoke it to initialize the view model. So, thus `CredentialViewModel` inherits same `ABaseViewModel` anyway, why wouldn't you just override `InitializeAsync` in your `CredentialViewModel` and call `ProcessOffer` from it?

```
    public CredentialViewModel(
        IUserDialogs userDialogs,
        INavigationService navigationService,
        ICredentialService credentialService,
        IAgentProvider agentContextProvider,
        IConnectionService connectionService,
        IMessageService messageService,
        IPoolConfigurator poolConfigurator,
        CredentialRecord credential
    ) : base(
        nameof(CredentialViewModel),
        userDialogs,
        navigationService
    )
    {
        _credential = credential;
        _credentialService = credentialService;
        _agentContextProvider = agentContextProvider;
        _connectionService = connectionService;
        _messageService = messageService;
        _poolConfigurator = poolConfigurator;

        _credentialState = _credential.State.ToString();
    }

    public override async Task InitializeAsync(object navigationData)
    {
        if (_credentialState != "Offered") return;
        await ProcessOffer();
    }
```

Anyway, you have to avoid calling asynchronous operations in constructors.

Comment: earlier it popup the dialogue box on `IndexPage` synchronously .. now, it only popup on `CredentialsViewMode.cs` page (didn't solved the problem)..

Comment: You can implement new common base class for your `CredentialViewModel` and `IndexViewModel` that will contain `ProcessOffer` method and `InitializeAsync`

Answer (score 0):

As you've already asked before, kicking off async code in the constructor of a class can be a can of worms. You should instead consider doing either:

1. Starting `ProcessOffer` in a lifecycle method instead. For instance when the View is showing call `ProcessOfferCommand`.
2. Using fire and forget to not block the constructor: `Task.Run(ProcessOffer)` you should probably avoid this though.
3. Use something like `NotifyTask` Stephen Cleary describes here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding you can find the complete code for it here: https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/blob/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs
4. Use a `CreateAsync` pattern with a private constructor. However, this doesn't work well with Dependency Injection usually. Doing IO intensive work during resolution isn't really the correct place to do it.

In my opinion using either 1. or 3. would be the best solutions, perhaps leaning towards a combination of 1. using NotifyTask that can notify you when it is done loading.

Comment: 1- can't override functions in `CredentialViewModel.cs`, it can be only used in `App.xml.cs` => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle

Comment: 2- `Task.Run(ProcessOffer)` didn't triggered the `ProcessOffer()`, not even synchronously

Comment: You do have appropriate events on the Page that you can use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.appearing?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: The `ProcessOffer()` is a function implemented in `CredentialViewModel`, but I want that, It should be triggered asynchronously everywhere on the App (`IndexViewModel` e.t.c).

Comment: this is what I want!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "It should be triggered asynchronously everywhere on the App".

Comment: If I'm on the `IndexPage`, and Web Application sends a request to Mobile Application, `ProcessOffer()`, should be triggered.. actually what `ProcessOffer` does is, that it asks the user to enter a PIN, if it's correct, it sends back a response to the Web Application.

Comment: I have no idea of what you have in your IndexPage, not sure why IndexPage itself would even contain behavior either. Unclear how anything is triggered in there. Provide a minimal reproducible sample, otherwise it will be hard to help you without any domain knowledge.

Comment: I added the code for `IndexViewModel.cs` and `App.xml.cs`. Kindly have a look. Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure you understood "minimal reproducible sample"